# Enumerate and Zip to access previous index

Tags: python, indexing, enumerate

When using zip do you need to use enumerate and convert the zip tuples to a list to access the previous index (i.e. index -1)

e.g.

```
list1 = [1, 3, 4, 8, 10]
list2 = [1, 3, 6, 7, 9]

combined_list = list(zip(list1, list2))

for i, v in enumerate(combined_list):
    if i > 0:
        print(combined_list[i-1])
```

Put simply, is that the most pythonic way?

Comment: Nah, just do `for v in combined_list[:-1]: print(v)`.

Comment: @superbrain Sorry, but that wouldn't allow the user to access the previous index during an iteration.

Comment: @AnnZen Not sure what you mean, but it does the same as the OP's code. Unlike yours.

Comment: @superbrain Oh, thank you! Can't believe myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list slice, or enumerate's second parameter, as pointed out before.

```
for i, v in enumerate( combined_list[1:] ):
    print( i, v, i-1, combined_list[i] )

for i, v in enumerate( combined_list, 1 ):
    print( i, v, i-1, combined_list[i] )
```

---

```
0 (3, 3) -1 (1, 1)
1 (4, 6) 0 (3, 3)
2 (8, 7) 1 (4, 6)
3 (10, 9) 2 (8, 7)
```

Comment: It would be more human-readable to `print( i+1, v, i, combined_list[i] )`